# easyUI datagrid inner edit combobox cannot selected default value

Tags: javascript, datagrid, combobox, jquery-easyui, inline-editing

easyUI datagrid inner editor load combobox cannot selected default value

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/consatan/EjpWn/6/) link

```
{field: "xx", title: "xx", width: 200, editor: {
type: "combobox",
options: {
    valueField: "xx",
    data: [
        {"xx": 1, text: "AAA", selected: true},
        {"xx": 2, text: "BBB"},
        {"xx": 3, text: "CCC"}
    ],
    onLoadSuccess: function(rows) {
        for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
            if(rows[i].selected) {
                $(this).combobox("setValue", rows[i].xx);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just try change this line

```
for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
```

to this one

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
```

it's tested and working.

or you can just do like this

```
onLoadSuccess: function(rows) {

      $(this).combobox("setValue",rows[-1].xx);

 }
```

this will always select the first value

Answer (score -2):

Try put the default value to index 0 not 1